# Programming language of a website

Tags: javascript, php, html

If I program a website in a language, say JavaScript. Then I make this website public like an usual website. Will people who use my website be able to tell what language it is programmed in?

Comment: HTML is not a programming language.

Comment: experienced programmers can detect..otherwise no way if you hide the source code

Comment: Then if I program a website in HTML, what language did I program it in? Also, sorry for the mistake, I edited the question, will people be able to tell?

Comment: @HasinduGajanayake Like an usual website so all you have is the website link and you can access it. But you have nothing that others dont have.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Essentially all websites are comprised of some combination of HTML, CSS and JavaScript.  There are libraries built on _top_ of these languages that they may also employ, and backend generative languages/systems for generating the HTML/CSS/JavaScript that will be deployed to the browser (Sprint in Java, .NET in C#, Django/Python, etc)-- those can often be detected as well.  What is your concern/question _specifically_?

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow-- I would recommend reviewing [ask] to learn how to better ask your questions.  A well-formed question will lead to more useful, high quality answers for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Code running in a browser **is always** discoverable by a visitor. Code running on a server **may not** be discoverable.

If you mean using JavaScript only on the server via NodeJS or similar solution, then no, there is not anything that will inherently expose the fact that you're using JavaScript on the server. Some languages whose filenames typically end in a known extension, (e.g. `.php`, `.asp`) **may** reveal the server-side language. But it's also easy for you (as the developer) spoof this if you wanted to for some reason.

However, any code running client-side can easily be explored by most browsers' developer tools. They even typically offer reformatting of minified HTML and JS.